# How do I Plot the Duration between two Dates in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, plot, data-visualization

I'm working with the following DataFrame:

```
First Bill Date Last Bill Date  Duration
0   2020-06-22  2021-01-06  0 Years 6 Months 14 Days
1   2020-07-06  2020-12-04  0 Years 4 Months 29 Days
2   2020-06-06  2020-10-01  0 Years 3 Months 25 Days
3   2020-07-21  2020-07-21  0 Years 0 Months 0 Days
4   2020-07-03  2020-09-16  0 Years 2 Months 13 Days
```

where `First Bill Date` and `Last Bill Date` are of type `TIMESTAMP`

, and `Duration` (type `str`) is the difference between the `First Bill Date` and `Last Bill Date`

`Duration` is calculated from the following function:

```
def date_difference(d1, d2):
    d1 = d1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    d2 = d2.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y-%m-%d")
    
    difference = relativedelta.relativedelta(d1, d2)

    years = difference.years
    months = difference.months
    days = difference.days
    
    return f'{abs(years)} Years {abs(months)} Months {abs(days)} Days'
```

Is there a way to plot `Duration` using any visualization package?

Please Advise.

Comment: Libraries like matplotlib or seaborn can generate your graph (pandas also uses matplotlib for this task) but the code depends on how you imagine this plot should be constructed. Do you have an example plot of your preferred representation?

Comment: Nothing specific, a simple bar chart would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you transform the duration into an integers of days, then it should be straight forward to plot it. So you could change your function to the following

```py
def date_difference(d1, d2):
    return (d2-d1).days
```

and then plot with `df['Duration'].plot()`

EDIT: I am assuming that `d2` is the later date, if that is not the case then you should reverse the ordering of course